# How can I drop duplicate data in a single column, group-wise in pandas?

Tags: python, group-by, pandas, duplicates

If the df is grouped by A, B, and C, and looks something like this:

```
    A    B      C    D
    1    53704  hf   51602
                     51602   
                     53802
                ss   53802
                     53802
    2    12811  hf   54205
                hx   50503
```

I have tried the following, which is similar to something from another post:

```
    df.groupby([df['A'], df['B'], df['C']]).drop_duplicates(cols='D')
```

This obviously incorrect as it produces an empty dataframe. I've also tried another variation with drop_duplicates that simply deletes all duplicates from 'D', no matter what group it's in. The output I'm looking for is:

```
    A    B      C   D
    1    53704  hf  51602
                    53802
                ss  53802
    2    12811  hf  54205
                hx  50503
```

So that duplicates are only dropped when they are grouped into the same A/B/C combination.

Comment: can't see any duplicates in your initial dataframe

Comment: oops. typo. fixed it and added a second duplicate to make things more obvious.

Comment: What output do you get? It works for me, either `df.groupby(('A','B','C')).drop_duplicates('D')` or `df.drop_duplicates().groupby(('A','B','C')`

Comment: This is a bit confusing as you are accessing these as columns (df['A']), but they are displayed like the index (is this just how you configured your repr?)... If there not columns, make them columns first, will be easiest.

Comment: So yes, they are actually indexes, as a result of a previous groupby manipulation. I'm really showing my lack of skills as yet, here, but how do I convert an index into a column? I've looked at the set_index and reindex documentation but I'm not making sense of it.

Comment: unstack doesn't work, because there are duplicate entries...

Comment: To further the comment stream to myself, what I was looking for is index_reset()!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming these are just columns, you can use [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) directly:

```
In [11]: df.drop_duplicates(cols=list('ABCD'))
Out[11]: 
   A      B   C      D
0  1  53704  hf  51602
2  1  53704  hf  53802
3  1  53704  ss  53802
5  2  12811  hf  54205
6  2  12811  hx  50503
```

If your interested in duplicates of *all* columns you don't need to specify:

```
In [12]: df.drop_duplicates()
Out[12]: 
   A      B   C      D
0  1  53704  hf  51602
2  1  53704  hf  53802
3  1  53704  ss  53802
5  2  12811  hf  54205
6  2  12811  hx  50503
```

Comment: accepting this answer because Andy pointed out I can only do this with columns, not indexes.

Answer (score 1):

Updating the syntax on the accepted answer. In pandas 1.1.1 + the following:

```
df.drop_duplicates(cols=list('ABCD'))
```

Should be changed to:

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset=list('ABCD'))
```