# Drop duplicates using pandas groupby

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, duplicates, unique

In the dataframe below, I would like to eliminate the duplicate `cid` values so the output from `df.groupby('date').cid.size()` matches the output from `df.groupby('date').cid.nunique()`.

I have looked at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19556165/how-can-i-drop-duplicate-data-in-a-single-column-group-wise-in-pandas) but it does not seem to have a solid solution to the problem.

```py
df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/108michael/ms_thesis/master/crsp.dime.mpl.df')
df.groupby('date')['cid'].agg(['size', 'nunique'])

       size  nunique
date        
2005      7        3
2006    237       10
2007   3610      227
2008   1318       52
2009   2664      142
2010    997       57
2011   6390      219
2012   2904      99
2013    7875    238
2014    3979    146
```

Things I tried:

1. `df.groupby([df['date']]).drop_duplicates(cols='cid')` gives this error: `AttributeError: Cannot access callable attribute 'drop_duplicates' of 'DataFrameGroupBy' objects, try using the 'apply' method`
2. `df.groupby(('date').drop_duplicates('cid'))` gives this error: `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'drop_duplicates'`

Comment: Your 2nd attribute error is simply caused by executing this: `('date').drop_duplicates('cid')`, it has nothing to do with pandas. Indeed, the error message is telling you that `'date'`, a `str` type object, doesn't have an attribute called `drop_duplicates`.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You don't need groupby to drop duplicates based on a few columns, you can specify a subset instead:

```
df2 = df.drop_duplicates(["date", "cid"])
df2.groupby('date').cid.size()
Out[99]: 
date
2005      3
2006     10
2007    227
2008     52
2009    142
2010     57
2011    219
2012     99
2013    238
2014    146
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 3):

##### 1. `groupby.head(1)`

The relevant `groupby` method to drop duplicates in each group is `groupby.head(1)`. Note that it is important to pass `1` to select the first row of each date-cid pair.

```py
df1 = df.groupby(['date', 'cid']).head(1)
```

##### 2. `duplicated()` is more flexible

Another method is to use `duplicated()` to create a boolean mask and filter.

```py
df3 = df[~df.duplicated(['date', 'cid'])]
```

An advantage of this method over `drop_duplicates()` is that is can be chained with other boolean masks to filter the dataframe more flexibly. For example, to select the unique cids in Nevada for each date, use:

```py
df_nv = df[df['state'].eq('NV') & ~df.duplicated(['date', 'cid'])]
```

##### 3. `groupby.sample(1)`

Another method to select a unique row from each group to use `groupby.sample()`. Unlike the previous methods mentioned, it selects a row from each group randomly (whereas the others only keep the first row from each group).

```py
df4 = df.groupby(['date', 'cid']).sample(n=1)
```

---

You can verify that `df1`, `df2` (ayhan's output) and `df3` all produce the very same output and `df4` produces an output where `size` and `nunique` of cid match for each date (as required in the OP). In short, the following returns True.

```py
w, x, y, z = [d.groupby('date')['cid'].agg(['size', 'nunique']) for d in (df1, df2, df3, df4)]
w.equals(x) and w.equals(y) and w.equals(z)   # True
```

and `w`, `x`, `y`, `z` all look like the following:

```
       size  nunique
date        
2005      7        3
2006    237       10
2007   3610      227
2008   1318       52
2009   2664      142
2010    997       57
2011   6390      219
2012   2904       99
2013   7875      238
2014   3979      146
```