# removing duplicates using group by in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, jupyter-notebook

I have a data-frame in which I am trying to remove duplicates using group-by.

```
data = {
    'Type': ['A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C','D','D'],
    'Key': ['ZPOC', 'adr#', 'name#', 'city#', 'adr#', 'city#', 'city#', 'ZZRE', 'ZPOC', 'adr#', 'name#', 'city#', 'adr#', 'city#', 'city#', 'ZZRE','item','item']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

In the Type column you can see the row starts from 'A'. So until next 'A' occurs it is my one group. From this group i want to remove duplicate rows by keeping the last occurance, based on values in Key column.

So consider the 1st group only (A-B-B-B-B-B-B-C). In this group adr# and city# is repeating twice so I want to keep the last occurance only from this duplicates. This process shall continue for every group.

**Note the duplicate rows should be removed only where Type = 'B'**

[image: desired output]
Desired Output

I almost got my desired output but the filtering is not working on Type = 'B'

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'Type': ['A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C','D','D'],
    'Key': ['ZPOC', 'adr#', 'name#', 'city#', 'adr#', 'city#', 'city#', 'ZZRE', 'ZPOC', 'adr#', 'name#', 'city#', 'adr#', 'city#', 'city#', 'ZZRE','item','item']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Create a mask for rows where 'Type' is 'A'
mask_a = df['Type'] == 'A'

# Create a new column 'Group' to identify the groups based on occurrences of 'A' in 'Type' column
df['Group'] = mask_a.cumsum()

# Filter and remove duplicates within each group

df = df.groupby('Group').apply(lambda x: x.drop_duplicates(subset='Key', keep='last') if (x['Type'] == 'B').any() else x)


# Drop the 'Group' column as it's no longer needed
df.drop('Group', axis=1, inplace=True)

df
```

[image: my output]

as you can see the duplicate rows where Type = 'D' has also been dropped which is suppose to be retained. Somehow I don't know why the filtering is not working.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deduplicate pandas dataset by index value without using \`networkx\`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76688653/deduplicate-pandas-dataset-by-index-value-without-using-networkx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can double `.groupby` + `.drop_duplicates`:

```py
out = df.groupby(df["Type"].eq("A").cumsum()).apply(
    lambda x: x.groupby("Type", group_keys=False).apply(
        lambda x: x.drop_duplicates(keep="last") if x["Type"].iat[0] == "B" else x
    )
)
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
        Type    Key
Type               
1    0     A   ZPOC
     2     B  name#
     4     B   adr#
     6     B  city#
     7     C   ZZRE
2    8     A   ZPOC
     10    B  name#
     12    B   adr#
     14    B  city#
     15    C   ZZRE
     16    D   item
     17    D   item
```

Answer (score 4):

Using [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
# is the value non-duplicated within a group starting in A?
m1 = ~(df.assign(group=df['Type'].eq('A').cumsum())
         .duplicated(subset=['group', 'Type', 'Key'], keep='last')
       )

# is the row not a B?
m2 = df['Type'].ne('B')

# keep if either is True
out = df.loc[m1|m2]
```

Output:

```
   Type    Key
0     A   ZPOC
2     B  name#
4     B   adr#
6     B  city#
7     C   ZZRE
8     A   ZPOC
10    B  name#
12    B   adr#
14    B  city#
15    C   ZZRE
16    D   item
17    D   item
```